# Writing SDK in javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

Im writing a  SDK for a project at work. This SDK will be used by js vanilla projects as well as a angular/react projects. I currently develop the sdk.js file as bunch of functions wrapped in a big IFFE. (Immediately invoked function expression). The problem is that it feels old and messy - I want to use modern modules (import,export keywords). What are my options? It is a js file and so i cannot use the import export kewords  without a development server. (even es modules as I understand). I consider develop this library (SDK) using import export keywords and bundle them into es5 code using webpack. How is this solution compared to simply use IIFE pattern without modules

Comment: So use a tool to transpile it to support whatever browser you need.

Comment: So for example develop the sdk using npm, webpack, babel, etc . . Then test the usage of the library by taking the bundle.js of webpack?

Comment: The question is Will I will be able to include this bundle.js and use it in the browser, without the need of server

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, you are correct - you should definitely consider implementing the sdk as a module (some call it a library).

if that is what you are after, i strongly recommand you to read:

- [Creating Node.js modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules)
- [You Don't Know JS - Modules](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#modules)

that should give your a staring point.

Comment: Okay but if I will develop that way, will a simple js file of tic tac tow will be a le to use that module without the need of local server?

Comment: @EvaCohen: correct. you just `require` the file the same way you develop everything in node

Comment: Mr. you are talking about node.I just mentioned that I would like a tic tac toe in vanilla js without dev server to be able to include the SDK and use it